# woocommerce_order_status_completed not called on stripe payment

Tags: php, stripe-payments, hook-woocommerce

I have written a custom plugin and part of this plug in uses the "woocommerce_order_status_completed" hook as:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'mmd_woointerface_order_complete', 1);
mmd_woointerface_order_complete($order)
{
 //print to log file here
}
```

I am using the stripe payment system and have checked and double checked the API Keys, have defined the Webhook end points as recommended by the woocommerce plugins.

1. I tried making a purchase and the system seem to respond correctly, with orders showing up in the backend of my site.
2. I have tried sending test webhooks using the strip backend.

None of these options cause the **mmd_woointerface_order_complete**, action to performed.  My custom call is never initiated.  Am I missing something.

Has any one got this to work with Stripe? Need help.

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**
If you use stripe and want to write code that gets called upon a payment.  The woocommerce stripe plugin has a whole other action hook sdk.

You can find the link to the calls here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/stripe/#section-13

The one that works best, but different from the standard woocommerce hooks is 
"wc_gateway_stripe_process_response ($stripe_response, $order)"

You will need to check the $stripe-response variable which is assigned one of the following string values:'succeeded', 'failed', 'pending', and 'on-hold'

This is the code I wrote and it works remarkably well.

```
function ProcessStripePayment($stripe_response, $order)
  {
    switch($stripe_response->status)
    {
    case 'succeeded';
       DebugLog('wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment HOOK FIRED  succeeded'); 
    break;

    case 'failed';
     DebugLog('wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment HOOK FIRED - failed'); 
    break;

    case 'pending';
        DebugLog('wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment HOOK FIRED - pending'); 
    break;

    case 'on-hold';
       DebugLog('wc_gateway_stripe_process_payment HOOK FIRED - on-hold');  
    break;          
    }   
  }
```

The other rather LARGE gotcha, is, as of now, this does not work in a plugin.  You have to put it in function.php OR I used a plugin called snippets.  That does the job.

The rest of the code you need to write is a off-take of the class structure.

```
$order               = new WC_Order( $order_id );
```

Pretty straight forward until you get to Meta_data, which is used by the woocommerce checkout fields. For that this works:

```
foreach($MetaData as $SubRow)
 {
 switch($SubRow->key)
   {
    case 'Your Custom Field Name':
    break;
   } // switch($SubRow->key) 

DebugLog($SubRow->key); 
DebugLog($SubRow->value);       
}   // foreach($MetaData as $SubRow)
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked:

add_action('wc_gateway_stripe_process_response', 'process_payment, 0, 2);
function process_payment($stripe_response, $order)
{
    if ($stripe_response->status === 'succeeded') { 
    }
}